# Send SMS to Email address using Android without Internet

Tags: sms, email, internet

I would like to know whether its possible to send an SMS text message to an email address in Android. Moreover, I need to send it without using Internet. I have heard of SMS to Email gateways but then how can one use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* possible to send emails to SMS inboxes. But you **can't send a SMS to an email inbox** given you do not have an internet connection. You must already know that emails require internet connectivity. As you asked, SMS gateways *can be* used to send and receive SMSes provided you are subscribed to a SMS line via a `Direct-to-mobile` or a `Direct-to SMS` gateway. Simply put, you cannot use this functionality with your normal SIM card, if you are willing to do it in an offline method. Read more about SMS Gateways in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway).

On a side note, if you can go online (say mobile data), you can do this by way of a MMS. All you have to do is to send the MMS to the desired email address. Some of the gateway addresses for email to SMS are listed below.

- Alltel: phonenumber@message.alltel.com
- AT&T: phonenumber@txt.att.net
- T-Mobile: phonenumber@tmomail.net
- Virgin Mobile: phonenumber@vmobl.com
- Sprint: phonenumber@messaging.sprintpcs.com
- Verizon: phonenumber@vtext.com
- Nextel: phonenumber@messaging.nextel.com
- US Cellular: phonenumber@mms.uscc.net

<sub>Keep in mind that most of the networks tend to block and/or alter their gateways once the traffic is considerably high, as this method is widely used by spammers.</sub>

Comment: thanks for the quick reply..so in short i can't send an sms message to an email address (without internet)...but I can send an email to SMS using email to SMS gateways...do u know gateway addresses for indian mobile carriers like Airtel etc that provide such service?

Comment: There is a complete list in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways). Remember not all the gateways work as carriers block these for regular users.

Comment: Hi...can I do something like this..i have a phone without internet connection..using this phone I send a SMS msg to another phone..and this another phone is connected to some desktop or server that has internet...so this 2nd phone will send the email..that will involve setting up of server etc..but then can you tell me if this is possible?

Comment: @Parth_90 Yes, as long as the second phone can use MMS and programmed to forward the messages to an email address.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can send SMS to email without internet. You just type in the email address where the phone number would go in the SMS address field. 
This has been possible for years, I did it in 2000 with a Nokia candy bar phone on a 2g network.
To go the other way, sending email to SMS, does require internet, and knowing the gateway address/carrier.